# Dojo: maintain reference to widget in event listener callback

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I have a Dojo widget that looks as follows:

```
define([
    // stuff...
], function(declare, lang, win, on, query,
    _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _OnDijitClickMixin, template){

    return declare("Toolbar", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _OnDijitClickMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        map: null,

        constructor: function(options) {
            // this.map set here
            lang.mixin(this, options);

            if (this.map === null) {
                console.log("Error: no map!");
            }
        },

        postCreate: function() {
            on(this.domNode, ".toolButton:click", this.loadTool);
        },

        // in the following function, this refers to element where event 
        // originated here   
        loadTool: function(e) {
            var clickedTool = "tools/Tool" + this.id[this.id.length - 1];

            require([clickedTool], function(Tool) {
                // Fails: want this.map to refer to map defined by constructor above
                (new Tool({ map: this.map })).placeAt(win.body());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

At the moment, this `Toolbar` widget is just an ordered list of buttons, each having class `toolButton`.  When a button is clicked, it will conditionally load the module (which returns another widget) associated to the clicked button.  For simplicity, the tool modules are named `tools/Tool<some_number>` where `<some_number>` is obtained from the `id` on the clicked button.

I need to pass the `map` property of the `Toolbar` widget into the constructor of the `Tool` widget as seen on this line:

```
(new Tool({ map: this.map })).placeAt(win.body());
```

However, as noted above, within `loadTool`, `this` refers to the button that was clicked and not to the `Toolbar` widget.  One possibility would be to called the event listener as

```
on(this.domNode, ".toolButton:clicked", lang.hitch(this, this.loadTool);
```

and then obtain the `id` of the clicked button from the event object...but this seems hacky and like the incorrect way to handle it.

What is the "best practice" for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to pass the context to the callback function, like your second approach. This allows you to control how a function executes, particularly in asynchronous operations.

From dojo documentation:

```
on(something, "click", processEvent);
```

> In asynchronous callbacks such as above, the context that the code is
>   executing in has changed. It will no longer refer to the object that
>   originally provided it, but its context will now refer to the
>   enclosing object, the callback. To get around this, you can use
>   hitch() to force the function to retain its original context.

The same code done properly will look like:

```
on(something, "click", lang.hitch(this, processEvent));
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-hitch

Comment: So this means I should obtain information about the DOM node where the event originated via the event object?

Comment: Yes make use of the event object, usually event.target is used. You can find more info on event object API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event